# Unable to Pass UserId through routing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, angular-ui-router

Trying to pass the UserId through a ui-sre using Razor Markup, but I run into the following error

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'df' is unexpected,
>   expecting [}] at column 17 of the expression [{ userId:
>   6981e6df-6004-4050-a721-f063fa73cbb1 }] starting at
>   [df-6004-4050-a721-f063fa73cbb1 }].
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$parse/syntax?p0=df&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%7D%5D&p2=17&p3=%7B%20userId%3A%206981e6df-6004-4050-a721-f063fa73cbb1%20%7D&p4=df-6004-4050-a721-f063fa73cbb1%20%7D

Layout.cshtml:

```
 @Using Microsoft.aspnet.identity

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="home ({ userId: @User.Identity.GetUserId() })">Home</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
                <li><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
```

state.js

```
                .state('home', {
                url: '/:userId',
                views: {
                    'main-body': {
                        templateUrl: '/app/views/home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController',
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    }
                }
            })
```

Not sure if I'm approaching passing the UserID in the best way or not...

Comment: Convert that GUID `ToString`

Comment: <li><a ui-sref="home ({ userId: @((User.Identity.GetUserId()).ToString()) })">Home</a></li>

I tried that but am getting the same error.

Comment: Got it by setting the ID to a constant

Comment: If you were able to solve the problem, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The constant thing I thought was working earlier did not either, however it was a simple matter if playing with the syntax a touch.

```
<li><a ui-sref="home ({ userId : '@User.Identity.GetUserId()'})">Home</a></li>
```